# observablearray not updating after .push

Tags: ajax, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I have a simple webpage where users can check their decks of cards, remove and add cards and I'm using knockout to keep things simple. When I click a button, following piece of code is executed:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: input.UrlAction_RemoveFromDeck,
    data: {
        accessToken: input.accessToken,
        id: el.Id
    }
}).done(function (data) {
    self.deck.splice(0, self.deck().length);
    console.log(self.deck().length);
    console.log("     ");
    data.Items.forEach(function (el, index) {
        var element = createElement(el);
        if (element.Id() !== 0)
            self.deck.push(element);
        console.log(self.deck().length);
    });
```

Service should remove an item from my deck and return my new deck. This part works and if I check the data returned I can actually see my new deck. After that I want to repopulate deck in view_model with new data and knockout should update DOM to reflect changes. I create new Element for each Item just because I add some ko.computed and methods to each one. Below is the console output:

```
0

1
2
3
4
```

also my markup:

```
<script type="text/html" id="deck-template">
    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-thumb" data-bind="style: { backgroundColor: color, 'background-image': 'url(' + ThumbnailUrl() + ')' }">
        <div class="card-desc" ><a data-bind="if: enabled, text: TitleUpper(), attr: { href: href }"></a></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</script>

<div id="deck" data-bind="template: { name: 'deck-template', foreach: deck }">
</div>
```

I deleted some of it because it's not relevant. I should add that I'm already using very similar piece of code (except URL and data send are different) to get the user deck at page load. Thanks for any help.

EDIT:

Added createElement function as requested:

```
function createElement(el) {
        var element = ko.mapping.fromJS(el);
        element.enabled = ko.observable(true);
        element.color = ko.observable(self.randColor());
        element.href = ko.observable(input.UrlAction_Reads + '?TrapId=' + el.SourceId);
        element.TitleUpper = ko.computed(function () { return element.Title().toUpperCase(); });
        element.add = function () {
            if (element.enabled()) {
                element.enabled(false);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: input.UrlAction_AddToUserDeck,
                        data: $.toDictionary({
                            accessToken: input.accessToken,
                            data: el
                        })
                    }).done(function (data) {
                        self.discover.remove(element);
                        self.deck.splice(0, self.deck().length);
                        data.Items.forEach(function (el, index) {
                            var element = createElement(el);
                            if (element.Id() !== 0)
                                self.deck.push(element);
                        });
                    }).always(function () {
                        element.enabled(true);
                    });
            }
        };
        element.remove = function () {
            if (element.enabled()) {
                element.enabled(false);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: input.UrlAction_RemoveFromDeck,
                    data: {
                        accessToken: input.accessToken,
                        id: el.Id
                    }
                }).done(function (data) {
                    self.deck.splice(0, self.deck().length);
                    console.log(self.deck().length);
                    console.log("     ");
                    data.Items.forEach(function (el, index) {
                        var element = createElement(el);
                        if (element.Id() !== 0)
                            self.deck.push(element);
                        console.log(self.deck().length);
                    });
                }).always(function () {
                    element.enabled(true);
                });
            }
        };
        return element;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the createElement function ?

Comment: can you post your viewModel too?

Comment: Are you sure that element.Id() !== 0 ?

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark Thank you, your comment made me go through entire code again and I found a problem. The thing is that array was updated properly and also HTML was changed, I just didn't call a necessary JS function to display the cards. Stupid bug but I spend 3 hours finding that one. Thank you.